# Gyroscope modeling parameters

Tags: gyroscope

Well im trying to model a gyroscope which is MPU-6050 and i am stuck in getting the missalignment and scale factor parameters from its datasheet ... 
And there is another problem that the names in each datasheet differs from the others 
My question is how to get those parameters?
Thanks !